# Loop through a project to open read-only view for a specific module

Tags: ibm-doors, readxl

I am new to dxl and I could not find on the internet what I am looking for. I am able to open a module in read-only mode using:

`module m = read("D/Fruits/ColorRed/Apples") //Where Project fruits, contains many folders Like ColorRed, ColorYellow, and in Color Red folder there are modules like apples, Cherries, Strawberries etc. which I would like to access`

But If I am only given the project name i.e. `Fruits`. Then how do I loop through the folders and modules inside and open for example Apples in read-only mode?

I have tried out the following code but  it does not work,

Here's what I have tried,

```
string MODULE_NAME = "Apples"
string PROJECT_NAME = "Fruits"

Module mod = null
for mod in PROJECT_NAME do (
   if (mod.name == MODULE_NAME)(
     read(mod.name)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the DXL manual at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSYQBZ_9.7.0/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/dxl_reference_manual.pdf, chapter 16 "Rational DOORS hierarchy", about the different loops available. I think you will need the loop "for all items in project", which has the operation "Assigns itemRef to be each successive undeleted item (for which the user has read access) in project, looping recursively through contained folders and projects.". In your case this would be

```
string MODULE_NAME = "Apples"
string PROJECT_NAME = "Fruits"

Project p = project "/" PROJECT_NAME
Item itemRef
Module mod = null

for itemRef in p do {
 // print fullName(itemRef) "\n"
 if (name (itemRef) == MODULE_NAME) {
   mod = read (fullName itemRef)
 }
}

if (!null mod) {
   …do something with the module…
   close (mod)
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, the code seems to work. Thank you for the input. But it reads all  the baselines for a given module whereas I want to access only the latest one. Could you please show me how it can be done?

Comment: I don't see how this loop opens any baseline. The perm to open a (current version of) a module is `Module read  (string, [bool, bool])`. The perm to open a baseline is `Module load ([Module], Baseline, bool)` or `Module load (ModuleVersion, bool)`.  How do you know that a Baseline has been opened? Perhaps post your code here.

Comment: The code is identical to what you have suggested. No change. But when I replace mod = read (fullName itemRef) with mod = read (name itemRef) then it only opens the current baseline.

Comment: That's really strange. `fullName itemRef` should resolve to "/Fruits/ColorRed/Apples", i.e. the module "Apples" in the project "Fruits", subfolder "ColorRed" . `name  itemRef` should just resolve to "Apples", i.e. the module "Apples" in the folder that is currently marked as `current`, which might be different from "/Fruits/ColorRed". Still I don't see any reference to a baseline. Still I wonder how you detect that a baseline has been opened. (note: "Baseline" is a fixed version that cannot b,e changed, "current version" is writable but shows the baseline it is based on in the title)